# Connector Choice for Arduino/MIDI Bridging Interface

Tags: audio, connector, midi

I'm in the early stages of planning a MIDI-mapping component that I can plug into my Alesis DM-6 drum kit so I can ultimately play it through Rock Band 3. I know there are commercial options out there, but I'm intrigued about building one (at probably 5x the cost, no doubt :P).  Everything I've read about this talks about requiring an extra set of patch cables to plug into each drum which then plugs into the Arduino black-box.

Anyway, my question is this: Is there a specific reason the connector of choice for each drum (not to mention guitars, etc.) is the 1/4" phono?  I could probably get away with a much smaller box if I can use 1/4" on the drum-plug side, but the smaller 1/8" (3.5mm) phono on the box-side. Am I losing anything by using 1/8"(3.5mm) connectors going into my device? Other than being more 'durable' or maybe having a tighter-fit, are there electrical or noise/interference/impedance/other issues using the smaller connectors?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "[phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio))" not "[phono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector)" plug (TR vs RCA). The phone plug is a 19th century invention for telephone switchboards so it was expected to survive very frequent usage. I guess 21st century bands and roadies still like things that are hard to break.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how there could be any difference between the two plugs, other than size.

There is some discussion of this issue on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/audioengineering/comments/fl6jf/differences_between_18_and_14_inch_adapter/).

To summarize that discussion, the consensus is that the 1/4" plug would be more durable, but otherwise exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

1/8" and 1/4" would be electrically equivalent.  Even if the 1/4" is a TRS (Tip, Ring, Sleeve) instead of just a TS (Tip, Sleeve), you can get the same electrical balanced connection from an 1/8" stereo plug hooked up for balanced mono audio.  If you support balanced audio, you could even get an adapter from XLR to 1/8".